# how to disable the second hoverinfo in R plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

I am using plotly to decompose all the factor of an evolution, I want to graph a bar diagram and then to add the "sum" as a marker, this way :

```
libelle <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C")
value <- c(1500000,987000,1540000,-600000,-627000,-1240000)
type <- c("gain","gain","gain","loss","loss","loss")
data <- data.frame(libelle,value,annee)
plot_ly(data=data,x=value,y=libelle,group=type,type="bar",orientation="h") %>% 
  group_by(libelle) %>% summarise(sum = sum(value)) %>%
  add_trace(x=sum,y=libelle,mode="markers",marker=list(color="black"),name="total")
```

All is fine with this graph, except for the hoverinfo : I would like to keep the hoverinfo of the first trace (when I over anywhere on a libelle, I get the info from both loss and gain), and with the second trace, it is replaced by another. I tried to put hoverinfo="none" in the add_trace, with no result.

any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to state which level you wanted the hover to appear by adding hoverinfo separately.

To show hover info for trace and not the bar plot:

```
plot_ly(data=data,x=value,y=libelle,group=type,type="bar",orientation="h", hoverinfo="none") %>% 
  group_by(libelle) %>% summarise(sum = sum(value)) %>%
  add_trace(x=sum,y=libelle,mode="markers",marker=list(color="black"),name="total", hoverinfo="all")
```

To show hover info for bar and not the trace markers:

```
plot_ly(data=data,x=value,y=libelle,group=type,type="bar",orientation="h", hoverinfo="all") %>% 
  group_by(libelle) %>% summarise(sum = sum(value)) %>%
  add_trace(x=sum,y=libelle,mode="markers",marker=list(color="black"),name="total", hoverinfo="none")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work : if I try your code to get info for bar and not the markers, I don't get the same hover as when I don't add trace at all (with plot_ly(data=data,x=value,y=libelle,group=type,type="bar",orientation="h"). In the second case, if I overmouse a bar, I get the info for the bar and the other bar from the same group, in the first case, only for the bar I overmouse.

Comment: @Malta you mean you needed A to show both gain and loss simultaneously?

Comment: yes, that's it, I want it to look exactly how it does when I have only
    plot_ly(data=data,x=value,y=libelle,group=type,type="bar",orientation="h")

Answer (score 0):

Create a `hovertemplate = paste("%{value} text <br>","text","<extra></extra>")`
this `<extra></extra>`, ends the trace.